# Why "Supports 5V VCC operation" appeared in LVC family datasheets?

Tags: digital-logic, low-power, 5v, 3.3v

Looking into the LVC logic chip family I was aure that it is 3.3 V supply devices. One of our fellows also confirms it [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/422577/80284). [This manual](http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/scba010/scba010.pdf) dated 1999 states that LVC is 5 V tolerant (version A), but not that it can be powered by 5 V. [This manual](http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/scbd152b/scbd152b.pdf) (dated 1998) states maximum absolute voltage to be 6.5 V for all the listed LVC chips, and operating voltage is 3.6 V max.

However looking through numerous "current" datasheets ([example](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74lvc1g04.pdf)) I see this "Supports 5V VCC operation" statement, absolute maximum 6.5 V, but recommended supply voltage up to 5.5 V.

Is it that LVC family - new manufactured chips and old ones - was upgraded or certified for the 5V operation? Or maybe 5 V supply applies to 1G/2G devices only - and LVC without these grades are still 3.3 V?

What are the cons for using 1G/2G LVC family for 5V power systems? Spikes/oscillation above 5.5 V at the inputs? Anything else? Let's consider that 5V is well regulated.

Answer (score 6):

The datasheet for a specific part is the law. Some parts in the LVC family were designed specifically to interface between different supply voltage levels, and their specifications will be different than standard logic chips. Your links are to entire **manuals** so it's difficult to figure out exactly which specifications you are talking about.

The "absolute maximum" supply voltage is the voltage that is likely to damage the device. You must never apply this voltage to the device, even for a short time.

You should focus on the "recommended operating conditions". TI specifies a maximum value for "Vcc Supply Voltage", and that voltage is significantly less than the absolute maximum. Remember this: the part may **not function properly** and **is not guaranteed to meet its specifications** and may have a **shortened lifetime** if you try to use the device outside of those recommended limits.

The term "5V tolerant" usually applies only to **input pins** rather than the supply voltage. It means that it is safe to apply voltages up to 5V to a specific input pin, even though the device operates at a lower voltage.

At the end of the day there is only one rule. Read and follow the datasheet for the **specific device** that you are using. If TI changed the datasheet to allow higher voltage operation then they must have improved the design or manufacturing process...they are allowed to **improve** their parts whenever they want. The **why** would be pure speculation...

As for the "cons" of using these parts, they are no different from the consideration for using any other part specified for the same operating and maximum voltages. **Do not** allow voltage spikes that exceed the maximum allowable voltages. Full stop.

Answer (score 5):

LVC stands for "Low-Voltage CMOS"; this family was originally not designed to work with a 5 V power supply.

LVC1G/2G/3G devices are newer and have additional features: not only full 5 V capability, but also support for partial power-down, i.e., when V<sub>CC</sub> = 0 V, all I/Os are allowed to be pulled high. (For those devices, see newer manuals like [How to Select Little Logic](http://www.ti.com/lit/pdf/scya049) or [Little Logic Guide](http://www.ti.com/lit/pdf/scyt129).)

Using LVC1G/2G/3G devices at 5 V is perfectly safe.

Answer (score -3):

In recent years,***CMOS*** **(AC/ACT, AHC/AHCT, ALVC, CBT, CBTLV, HC/HCT, LVC, LV/LV-A)

and *BiCMOS*(ABT, ALVT, BCT, FB, GTL, and LVT)**  have further strengthened their position in the semiconductor market.

However, when designing systems using CMOS and BiCMOS devices, one must **understand the characteristics of these families** and the way inputs and outputs behave in systems.  It is **very important for the designer to follow all rules and restrictions** that the manufacturer requires, as well as to design within the data-sheet specifications. Because datasheets do not cover the input behaviour of a device in detail, this application report explains the input characteristics of CMOS and BiCMOS families in general. Understanding the behaviour of these inputs results in more robust designs and better reliability.

[image]

REF: SCBA004D–July 1994–RevisedSeptember2016

### Conclusion

Although the AVC still uses a std.CMOS input, its Vt and RdsOn is higher than the output stage RdsOn so Vdd currents and voltages for linear inputs are tolerated with hidden series R’s and quad ESD Schottky diode clamps. Perhaps these have been optimized for Vin>Vdd tolerance , yet all CMOS have these hidden ESD protection circuits typically using 10k R between diode pairs.    Notice this have max current at LVT TTL input thresholds rather than Vdd/2, but may not apply to every one of the above families.